# typescript is not generating correct system.register

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, systemjs

So, my problem is:

I have the following structure of application files:

[Working Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQddn.png)

When I it tsc the same structure is generated but under the dist directory

the compilation configuration is set to something like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir":"dist",
        "module": "system", //commonjs, amd ( requirejs ) , system
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false

    }
}
```

I'm loading modules with Systemjs on index.html, something like this:

```
  System.config({
         baseURL : "dist",  
      });

      System.import('Application.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

the Application.ts file is something like this:

```
import {SelectedProducts} from "./Controllers/SelectedProducts";

export class Application  {

    constructor(private controller:SelectedProducts){

    }
 // some methods here

 }
```

and the Application.js file generated is something like this:

```
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Application;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            Application = (function () {
                function Application(controller) {
                    this.controller = controller;
                }
  // methods go here

       }());
            exports_1("Application", Application);
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone has any ideia why is this happening ?

This is not the only case where the system.register is not as expected.

My ProductsController.ts was also bad generated:

ProductsController.ts source:

```
import {ProductsRepository} from "../Models/ProductsRepository";
import {EditProductView} from "../Views/EditProductView";
import {ListProductsView} from "../Views/ListProductsView";
import {Product} from "../Models/Product";
import {ProductsViewModel} from "../Views/ProductsViewModel";
import {ValidationProvider} from "../Validation/ValidationProvider";

export class SelectedProducts {

    public constructor(private productsRepository:ProductsRepository, 
    private editView:EditProductView,
    private listSelectedView:ListProductsView,
    private validation:ValidationProvider){

    } 
// some methods here

}
```

js generated code:

```
System.register(["../Models/Product", "../Views/ProductsViewModel"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Product_1, ProductsViewModel_1;
    var SelectedProducts;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (Product_1_1) {
                Product_1 = Product_1_1;
            },
            function (ProductsViewModel_1_1) {
                ProductsViewModel_1 = ProductsViewModel_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            SelectedProducts = (function () {
                function SelectedProducts(productsRepository, editView, listSelectedView, validation) {
                    this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
                    this.editView = editView;
                    this.listSelectedView = listSelectedView;
                    this.validation = validation;
                }

            }());
            exports_1("SelectedProducts", SelectedProducts);
        }
    }
});
```

Any Ideias ?

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, module imports that are not used as a value, will be elided from the output. The rational that this is that you can use a type from a module at design time, but do not intend to use it as a run time dependency. In this case, the only use of `SelectedProducts` was as a type annotation to the constructor parameter.

Use `import "./Controllers/SelectedProducts";` to ensure the module import is preserved.

Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit for more information about module import elision.